# Flexbox align center with another element in right of it

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I want to implement page that looks like
[image: this picture]

It has `next button` that must in `absolute position` in the middle of the page, and next to it there is `skip button` that the text must center with `next button`'s text.
I am struggling to make this happen using `flexbox`, maybe someone can help me.
so far my code is like this

component:

```
  <View style={{ alignSelf: 'center', position: 'absolute' }}>
    <Button
      buttonStyle={styles.nextButton}
      onPress={this._onPress}
      activeOpacity={0.9}
    >
      <Text style={styles.nextText}>NEXT</Text>
    </Button>
    <Text
      style={styles.skipButton}
      onPress={this._onSkipPress}
    >
      SKIP
    </Text>
  </View>
```

styles:

```
  nextButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: 52,
    width: 128,
    borderRadius: 26,
    bottom: 24,
    elevation: 1
  },
  skipButton: {
    marginRight: 20,
    fontSize: 14
  },
```

I know that this is `react-native` code, but if you can solve it using `css`, I believe I can convert it to `react-native`.
Note: please use `flexbox` only

Comment: share full code

Comment: @TemaniAfif done, but it is in `react-native`

Answer (score 3):

You can create one `div` element for buttons and use `position: absolute` on it and also on last button.

```css
.page {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #4AA1CC;
  position: relative;
}
.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 50px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
button {
  color: white;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
.buttons button:first-child {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #32D6B6;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.buttons button:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: -60px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button>Next</button>
    <button>Skip</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: next button must in center of the page and skip button will be in right of it.

Comment: @2r83 See update.

Comment: cool, but can you make it using `flexbox` since my question is using `flexbox` only